# What part of this code references my library's "view"?

Tags: list-view

SharePoint 2010 is limits the selection control for a list/library's view in a webpart to the first 50 available. I need to select view # 5x... What part of the code below can I edit to make the webpart diplay the view I want?

```
WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" Description=""
ListDisplayName="" PartOrder="2" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="False"
IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True"
ExportControlledProperties="False" IsIncludedFilter="" DataSourceID=""
Title="Related Courses" ViewFlag="8388745" NoDefaultStyle=""
AllowConnect="True" FrameState="Normal"
CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.gif" PageSize="-1"
PartImageLarge="/_layouts/images/itdl.gif" AsyncRefresh="False"
Dir="Default" DetailLink="/CSMD/marketingcommunity/Marketing Course Library"
ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="48f49a86-c61c-413b-86a5-5786560cec68"
AllowClose="False" ListName="{48F49A86-C61C-413B-86A5-5786560CEC68}"
FrameType="TitleBarOnly" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True"
SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="False"
ViewGuid="{E788A8D4-D7B8-428F-B702-8A138ED14881}" ChromeType="TitleOnly"
AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="False"
WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ViewContentTypeId="0x"
InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl"
MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." HelpMode="Modeless"
ListUrl="" ID="g_e788a8d4_d7b8_428f_b702_8a138ed14881"
ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True"
TitleUrl="/CSMD/marketingcommunity/Marketing Course Library"
ManualRefresh="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup"
__WebPartId="{E788A8D4-D7B8-428F-B702-8A138ED14881}"
__AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""
```

Comment: Zork - Thanks for the clean-up! I hadn't realized that was a formatting option :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this chunk:

`ViewGuid="{E788A8D4-D7B8-428F-B702-8A138ED14881}"`

Comment: I'll give this a shot as soon as I return to the project. Thanks, Abe!